# getting authenticated user onAuthenticationSuccess

Tags: php, symfony, php-5.3, fosuserbundle

I have the following authentication handler:

```
class LoginAuthSuccessHandler implements AuthenticationSuccessHandlerInterface, AuthenticationFailureHandlerInterface
{
    private $router;
    private $container;

    /**
    * Constructor
    * @param RouterInterface   $router
    */
    public function __construct(RouterInterface $router, $container)
    {
        $this->router = $router;
        $this->container = $container;
    }

    public function onAuthenticationSuccess(Request $request, TokenInterface $token)
    {
        if ($request->isXmlHttpRequest()) {
            $user =  $this->container->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser();
            $result = array('success' => true, 'user' => $user);
            return new Response(json_encode($result));
        } else {
            $route = $this->router->generate('ShopiousMainBundle_profile');

            $referrer_url = $request->server->get('HTTP_REFERER');
            if (strstr($referrer_url, '/items/')) {
                 $route = $referrer_url;
            }

            return new RedirectResponse($route);
        }
    }

    public function onAuthenticationFailure(Request $request, AuthenticationException $exception)
    {
        if ($request->isXmlHttpRequest()) {
            $result = array('success' => false, 'message' => $exception->getMessage());
            return new Response(json_encode($result));
        } else {
            // Handle non XmlHttp request here
        }
    }
}
```

why is it that:

```
$user =  $this->container->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser();
```

returns null? how do i get the authenticated user at this point?

Answer (score 9):

You should use the `$token` variable you are receiving as an argument instead of `$this->container->get('security.context')->getToken()`.

```
$user = $token->getUser();
```

Answer (score 3):

```
public function onAuthenticationSuccess(Request $request, TokenInterface $token)
{
    $user = $token->getUser();
}
```

that's all ;)

Answer (score 0):

maibe you don't set your provider in security.yml.

```
security:
 provider:
  example:
   entity: {class Acme\AuctionBundle\Entity\User, property: username}
```

Replace the Bundle and the entity by yours.

Comment: i did set the provider

Answer (score 0):

The only way I found was to inject the entityManager,

```
calls:
    - [setEntityManager,[@doctrine.orm.entity_manager]]
```

get the username from the request and query for the user, using that username.

```
$userRepo->findByEmail($request->get('_username'));
```